# How to get path of conda env from its name?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

When I do `conda info --envs`, I get list of all envs and their locations like this:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/mbp/miniconda3
myenv              /Users/mbp/miniconda3/envs/myenv
```

Is there a way to get the location of `myenv` environment from command line? May be something like `conda info --envs myenv` to get

```
/Users/mbp/miniconda3/envs/myenv
```

**What's the use case?**
I want to cache all the environment dependencies in GitHub actions. This has to happen before the environment is activated. If I know the location of the environment, I can cache all the files in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
conda info --envs | grep -Po 'myenv\K.*' | sed 's: ::g'
```

This bash command will retrieve all envs from conda and find the line which starts from `myenv` and give it to the `sed` command which inturn removes the spaces

surprisingly it worked for me

Comment: Not working. Giving me `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

Comment: Check the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BrokenPipeError it's a connection error somewhere in the code. this command is not responsible for that

Answer (score 5):

```
$(conda info --base)/envs/myenv
```

Answer (score 2):

Conda's internal function to handle prefix resolution (`locate_prefix_by_name`) is currently located in `conda.base.context`, so one could avoid listing all envs with a script like:

**conda-locate.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n base python

import sys
from conda.base.context import locate_prefix_by_name

print(locate_prexif_by_name(sys.argv[1]), end='')
```

**Usage**

```bash
# make executable
chmod +x conda-locate.py

./conda-locate.py jupyter
# /Users/user/miniforge/envs/jupyter
```

You may want to add a try..catch to handle the `conda.exceptions.EnvironmentNameNotFound` exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but all of the responses currently rely on the format of the output of a `conda` command designed to be read only by humans.

You can pass `--json` to get machine-parseable output then use `jq` to extract the information you need in a reliable way.

As you can see by running `conda info --json`, the machine-parseable version does not actually include environment names...this is because the environment's name is **defined** by the name of the environment's containing folder, so you can just do something like

```bash
$ conda info --json | jq -r '.envs[] | select(. | endswith("/${YOUR_ENV_NAME}") )'
```

- `-r` to output the raw string (not JSON)
- `.envs[]` to get the list of all environment locations
- `| select( ... )` to filter our just the one you want
- a slash before the environment name to prevent issues with environments whose names are a suffix of another environment name.